# java.lang.VerifyError when mocking Swing static methods

Tags: java, swing, static-methods, powermock

I am using PowerMock to mock static methods on `JOptionPane`, but the JRE doesn't seem to be very conform with it, because I get a `java.lang.VerifyError` at initialisation, as it checks the integrity of its own packages and classes.

I have though of a few workarounds, but I'm not very happy with any of them:

- Write an object wrapper for `JOptionPane` and provide an interface for the methods I need (`showInputDialog`, etc.), so I can inject a mock or an stub for testing. This just moves the problem elsewhere, as I would still need to cover my wrapper methods, but at least they will be isolated from the logic.
- <strike>Use an instance of `JOptionPane` instead the class reference to call the methods upon it (I think I won't have any problems mocking an instance, as the class is not final). The downside is that I will get lots of warnings of the kind "invoking static method on an instance variable", but that's the price to pay.</strike>
- Do not mock `JOptionPane` at all and use `Robot` to fire the input events to handle it. This can be very cumbersome and not very robust... Besides that, I am using internal dialogs, and that requires extra work to set up the `JDesktopPane`, `JInternalFrame`s and so on.

Any other ideas or suggestions?

Thanks!

update: by te way, I've tried mocking a `JOptionPane` *instance* and it seems that the method dispatcher ignores the instance picks directly the previously existing static method (it makes sense, after all), so the second option is discarded.

Answer (score 2):

- Write a wrapper for `JOptionPane` - this is definitely the most robust option, and also allows you to write convenient short-hand methods for yourself.  I'd pick this one.  If, like myself and most other developers, you already have some GUI helper class somewhere in your project, they can go there.
- Use an instance - not a bad solution, but definitely not as easy to manage as a call to a single static method.  I wouldn't say the added complexity was worth it.
- Use a `Robot` to mock the inputs - yes, that sounds extremely fragile to me.  You become dependent on the internal structure and implementation details of `JOptionPane` at that point, which is not a good place to be.  `JOptionPane`s' behaviors and button order may also vary under different look-and-feels (i.e. OK, Cancel vs. Cancel, OK).  Finally, this won't work in a headless environment (although if you're already using `JOptionPane`s in your tests, and plan on always testing on a desktop machine, that isn't a concern).